# Better way to include .cpp files in Test Project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am currently writing a C++ program using Visual Studio.

Now, I wanted to add a second Test project which is supposed to contain my unit tests. The problem is now, that if I want to test my own code, I have to add every .cpp file of the source files from my main project to the second project, even though I included the headers. Is there a better alternative?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Create a library from the code to test, and link that one to your test project.

Comment: I read that this is a way to do it, but if I can, I would like to avoid it.

Comment: _"I would like to avoid it."_ Why? Any specific reasons for that?

Comment: Would need another project and split the code base up more. It's mainly an aesthetic concern.

Comment: It's good and clean actually to have a separate project for the testing code, and a modularized library for the code under test. I can't see what's more aesthetic to have a whole spaghetti bunch of files within one big single project.

Comment: Okay, then I will probably do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can follow the next way:

1. Split your main project into executable and static or dynamic library
2. Move all your code that needs testing into such library, and include its `.h` and `.lib` into your executable
3. Do the same with your `Test` project

I'll try to explain my idea with the next example:

Project `MyProject`:

main.cpp:

```
#include "my_vector.h"
#include "my_matrix.h"

int main()
{
    MyVector vect;
    MyMatrix matrix;

    // some operations with vect and matrix
}
```

my_vector.h:

```
#pragma once

struct MyVector
{ 
    // fields and methods for MyVector
}
```

my_vector.cpp:

```
#include "my_vector.h"

// definitions of methods for MyVector
```

my_matrix.h:

```
#pragma once

struct MyMatrix
{ 
    // fields and methods for MyMatrix
}
```

my_matrix.cpp:

```
#include "my_matrix.h"

// definitions of methods for MyMatrix
```

Project `Test`:

main.cpp:

```
// depends on what testing framework do you use
```

my_vector_test.cpp:

```
#include "my_vector.h"

// code for MyVector testing
```

my_matrix_test.cpp:

```
#include "my_matrix.h"

// code for MyMatrix testing
```

What you do:

1. Keep in `MyProject` only file `main.cpp`
2. Add project `MyMath` and move `my_vector.h`, `my_vector.cpp`, `my_matrix.h`, `my_matrix.cpp` into that
3. Add `MyMath.lib` to link for `MyProject`
4. Add `MyMath.lib` to link for `Test`
5. Profit!

Answer (score 0):

This question is old and already has a answer, but I thought that's worthy to mention another way to solve the problem of include cpp file in a test project.

I came across this problem recently because I couldn't afford to encapsulate all what I want to test inside a lib static project, so I ended up making a unity build in the test project.

Unity build consite in have a cpp file in the test project, usually called "UnityBuild.cpp". Inside it, you have to include "#include" all the cpp file that you want.

More about Unity Builds (it's old, but, it's a good reading)
https://buffered.io/posts/the-magic-of-unity-builds/